# Diff and ignore lines missing in one file

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, diff

I want to diff two files and ignore lines that are present in one file but missing in the other.

For example

**File1:**

```
foo
bar
baz
bat
```

**File2:**

```
foo
ball
bat
```

I'm currently running the following diff command

```
diff File1 File2 --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format=''
```

Which in this case would produce

```
bar
baz
```

as the output, i.e. only missing or conflicting lines. I would like to only print conflicting lines, i.e. ignore cases where one line is missing from File2 and is present in File1 (not the other way around). Is there any way to do something like this using diff or do I have to resort to other tools? If so, what would you recommend?

Comment: If your input files could be sorted, the `comm` command might do what you want (assuming it is available under cygwin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might also take a look at [`comm`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/comm.html), if you have it available:

```
comm [-1] [-2] [-3 ] file1 file2
-1 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file1.
-2 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file2.
-3 Suppress the output column of lines duplicated in file1 and file2.
```

The input files should be sorted. However, you can modify the default behavior with --nocheck-order option, if available.

In your case you would want `comm --nocheck-order -23 file filter_file`

Answer (score 0):

When you say conflicting, do you mean entries that appear in both File1 and FIle2?

If so, use the following -

Create a shell script called mycmopare.sh and put the below into it.

```
#!/bin/bash
File1Contents=$(cat File1)

for i in $File1Contents; do
   grep $i File2
done
```

Run mycompare.sh from the directory where File1 and File2 are stored.

Output:

```
foo
bat
```