# Find directories with all files inside older than X?

Tags: linux, find, directory-listing

Is it possible on linux to find directories where all contained files and directories (and sub-directories' files etc.) are older than a given age? In other words, if a directory has one or more files within that have a modification date more recent than a given threshold, that directory *should not* be listed. If *all* of the files and folders below that directory are *older* than the given threshold, then that directory *should* be listed.

The use case is that my home directory is full of hidden directories, and I'm sure that many of them are left overs from previous installations, and software that I haven't used in years. I'd like to be able to find these directories, so I can easily decide whether to cull them.

Comment: What do you mean by "older": modification or access time? Note that the latter will be meaningless if the file system is mounted with `relatime` or `noatime`. Also a very old modification time doesn't necessarily mean that a file is useless.

Comment: @cyrus modification time. I know it doesn't mean it's useless. As I said, I just want to use this as a tool to help me to decide what is useless..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably possible to do this without creating files using process substitution or something, but here's a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq > old.txt
find . -type f -mtime -30 -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq > new.txt
grep -vf new.txt old.txt
```

The first command outputs the path of every file modified more than 30 days ago (in find's `-printf` -- at least with the GNU find on my system -- `%h` prints the whole path except for the actual filename), then sorts those and gets rid of any duplicates, and puts the whole thing into a file called `old.txt`.

The second command does the same but with every file modified less than 30 days ago, and puts them into another file, `new.txt`.

The grep line prints every line from old.txt that doesn't appear in new.txt -- so it will give you a list of directories that contain *only* files that were last modified more than 30 days ago.

This is all using the GNU versions of the utilities. I don't know if the syntax matches up on the BSD versions, etc.

Comment: Nice. That's a neat solution!

Comment: grep can be slow and memory intensive if the directory listing is huge. In this case you could use comm instead. Refer http://superuser.com/questions/409493/diff-and-ignore-lines-missing-in-one-file

Answer (score 7):

Finally figured out the magic one-liner:

```
for dir in `find . -type d -mtime +30`; do test `find $dir -type f -mtime -30 -print -quit` || echo $dir; done
```

This prints any directories that have a modification time greater than 30 days and no files modified within the last 30 days.

Comment: Nice. That is very cool.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
for DIR in {the folder list}; do
   if [[ $(find ${DIR} -mtime -10 -type f) == "" ]]; then 
        echo ${DIR}
   fi
done
```

It finds all directories in {the folder list}, that contains files older than 10 days.

Basically what `find ${DIR} -mtime -10 -type f` does is to find all files (`-type f`) that are modified within 10 days (`-mtime -10`, which is different from `-atime` or `-ctime`, see here for more information: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/).  If such files are not found within a directory, then we know that this directory is older than 10 days, and we output this directory with `echo ${DIR}`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: When you suggest a solution to a problem, it is most helpful, also for future readers, to explain in some detail why your solution works. The key point here is the use of the `-mtime` option of `find`: which units does it use (minutes,hours,days), how does it differ from `atime`, thin kind of things.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for your advice, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f -mtime +30
```

to check files older than 30 days

if you add `-iname '.*'` it will show you the hidden files

or `-type d` for directories

Comment: Yes, I know this. I'm not looking for files older than the date, I'm looking for directories which **only contain** files and directories which are all older than the given date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following workaround to implement your need:

```
$ touch -t 201206010100 some_file
$ find . -newer some_file
```

At touch man page:

```
-t STAMP
    use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

**There is also -d option of touch but i haven't used it. You could give it a try.**

[Edit]
you could use touch -d option as follows to generate a file at a given date:

```
$ touch -d "Wed Jun 27 09:44:44 EEST 2012" some_file
$ ls -l some_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2012-06-27 09:44 some_file
```

The you could use the same approach i mentioned above

Comment: See my comment on Petkaux answer. This doesn't solve my question, and it's also a bit nutty, Why wouldn't I just use `find -newert 201206010100` ?

Comment: you could use -d option on touch command which will enable you to create file at a given date.

Comment: Before you spend more time on this answer, I think you should re-read the question. It is not asking what you think it is asking.