# Find directories that contain more than one file of the same extension

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I’m using Debian 8.0 and would like for example to find directories that contain more than 1 `.mkv` file. I tried this and it failed:

```
find -type d -exec find {} -name '*.mkv' | wc -l\;
```

There is a similar [Q&A here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/441606/find-directories-with-all-files-inside-older-than-x), which I wasn’t able to adapt. This didn't work for me either:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; find '{}' -name '*.mkv' | wc -l" \; |   awk '$NF>=2'
```

The error message points to a syntax error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The reason for this is that the directory has a name like this:

```
Directory With Space and (Brackets)
```

Comment: Make find -exec `dirname` and redirect output to a file. Use sort and uniq to see how many mkv's in each dir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest instructing find to look for all the files and print out the containing directory of each match, so you won't need to worry about parsing weird  strings.  Then use uniq to count the duplicates printing out those occurring more than once. e.g.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mkv' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -cd
```

**Edit** Replaced awk with `uniq -cd` per Scott's suggestion

Comment: Excellent!  My first thought was something like `find -d -exec sh -c 'ls -d {}/*.mkv | wc -l' | …`; your solution is much more elegant.  Suggestion: use `uniq -cd` and you can eliminate the `awk`.

Comment: Works as advertised. Need to look up awk, seems very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I might try something like this:

```
 find dirname -type f -name '*.mkv' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 dirname | sort | uniq -c | egrep -v '^ *1 ' | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

The find outputs the names of all the .mkv files, then the xargs does a dirname on everything to extract only the directory name, sort all the entires, have uniq provide a count of repeated lines and using egrep remove those having only 1 *.mkv file and finally remove the counts using the sed to provide a list of directories only.

BTW, -print0 is being used so that special character filename do not cause problems xargs needs the -0 switch to interpret the input correctly in that case..  As noted in the comments the exception is of course a newline character as part of the filename which I personally have not encountered.  xargs needs the -0 switch to interpret the input correctly in that case.

Comment: This will handle _filenames_ containing newlines, but not directory names, because, if you have a file whose pathname is `abc⏎def/foo.mkv` where `⏎` represents a newline), then `dirname` will output `abc⏎def`, so the `sort` will see two independent lines: `abc` and `def`.

Comment: Point taken....however I think newlines would be very rare.

Comment: I agree; but my point is: why make a point of handling pathological input if you don’t handle all of it?  At the very least, it’s a question of disclosure: your last paragraph could lead readers into a false sense of security.

Comment: Tested and works as advertised.

Comment: This works on my mac!  
Remember to replace "dirname" and ".mkv" with the appropriate directory to search and file extension, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack but that's what I would do:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d)
do
  if [ $(ls -l "$dir" | grep '\.mkv$' | wc -l) -ge 2 ]
  then
    echo "$dir"
  fi
done
```

How this works:

1. Find all subdirectories of the current directory `find . -type d` and loop over them with every directory being saved in the variable `dir`
2. If the directory contains more than 2 mkv files, print the content of `$dir`

**Update:**
My bad, I forgot the **more than 2** part of your question. This should be fixed by using `-ge` instead of `-eq` (the above is already fixed)!

Answer (score 0):

A perl solution

`perl -le 'use File::Find; find (sub {if(/\.mkv$/) {$d{$File::Find::dir}++}}, "."); END {for (sort keys %d) {print if $d{$_}>1}};'`

This code is similar to others.  The treewalk (of current directory ".") is counting the directory whenever it encounters a .mkv file (stored in the %d hash).  After the walk, all directories with more than 2 files are printed out.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? In any case OP was asking about find not looking for a perl solution.

Comment: Sure, added.  I don't see anything in the OP asking about a `find` solution specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I was looking to exploit a typical set of linux tools.  I was looking to avoid having to do this in python for example.